# QAudioInput stops send data in tabWidged when tab changed

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qaudioinput

All!
I have some application with 3 tabs, one tab initialized QWidget from other tab. I start QAudioInput in constructor(read to memory, I don't need file)  - it starts works. But when I change tab to my widget, data stops and audioInput has status isActive still.
I have changed and minimized sources. It is a cross-compilation for ARM Linux platform. Now it is works usiallu, but few changes active tab crash stream.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication myapp(argc, argv);
    Widget wid;
    wid.show();
    return myapp.exec();
}
```

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Default widget in new tab
    wMetod = new Vnimi(this);//this
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(1, wMetod, "Empty"); // Set Tab's name

    ui->pButton_Vnimi->setChecked(true);
    /*QButtonGroup **/
    grMetod = new QButtonGroup(this);
    grMetod->addButton(ui->pButton_Vnimi );
    grMetod->addButton(ui->pButton_ExpVibro);
    grMetod->setExclusive(true);
    connect(grMetod, static_cast<void(QButtonGroup::*)(QAbstractButton *)>(&QButtonGroup::buttonPressed),
        [=](QAbstractButton *button){ metChanged(button); });

    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Widget::metChanged(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    /* switch for strings */
    if( button->objectName() =="pButton_Empty" ) {
        ui->tabWidget->removeTab(1);
        wMetod->disconnect(); delete wMetod;
        wMetod = new Vnimi(this);//this
        ui->tabWidget->insertTab(1, wMetod, "Empty"); // Set Tab's name
    }else if( button->objectName() =="pButton_Input" ) {
        ui->tabWidget->removeTab(1);
        wMetod->disconnect(); delete wMetod;
        wMetod = new VibrExpr(this);//this
        ui->tabWidget->insertTab(1, wMetod, "Input"); // Set Tab's name
    }else {
        qDebug() << "Unknow method!";
    }
    qDebug() << button->objectName() << " pressed";
}
```

```
VibrExpr::VibrExpr(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VibrExpr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lb_level->setText( QString().number(minLevel) );

    QAudioFormat frmt;
    frmt.setCodec( "audio/pcm"), frmt.setChannelCount( 2);
    frmt.setSampleRate( 44100), frmt.setSampleType( QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    frmt.setSampleSize( 16);

    rawSrc = new QAudioInput(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice(), frmt, this);
    rawSrc->setNotifyInterval(250);
    connect(rawSrc, SIGNAL(notify()), this, SLOT(slot()));
    connect(rawSrc, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this,  SLOT(iStateChanged(QAudio::State)));

    buff = new QBuffer(this);
    buff->open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
    connect(buff, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(newData()) );

    rawSrc->start(buff);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,  SLOT(timSlot()) );
    timer->start(1000);

    qDebug() << "Created";
}

void VibrExpr::timSlot()
{
    int sbVal = ui->lb_level->text().toInt();
    if(sbVal < -6 ) {
        sbVal += 1;
    }
    if(buff != nullptr)  \
    if(buff->isOpen() && sbVal >= -10) {
        qDebug() << "Sz " << buff->size();
        rawSrc->stop();
        buff->close();
        qDebug() << " Input closed";
    }
    ui->lb_level->setText( QString().number(sbVal));
    if(rawSrc != nullptr)  qDebug() << "iStat " << rawSrc->state();
}

void VibrExpr::newData(void)
{
    int k = buff->size();
    QByteArray qba = buff->read(k);
    buff->seek(0);
    buff->buffer().remove(0, k);
    qDebug() << "n=" << k;
}

void VibrExpr::slot(void)
{
    qDebug() << "USec:" << rawSrc->processedUSecs() ;
}

void VibrExpr::iStateChanged(QAudio::State state)
{
    qDebug() << "Now state: " << state;
}
```

Comment: Can you extend your example to show how you create the widget whose constructor contains the snippet above? Unfortunately only from this snippet the cause of the issue is not apparent

Comment: Added to started post, @zgyarmati

Comment: I'll minimize my app tomorrow for localisation problem.

Comment: New iteration with minimized code(all is here).